# time conversioin in hour and minutes from integer

Tags: objective-c

I am calculating time using this formula Time  = distance/speed.
   For example  Time = 34.5/40 = 0.8625 
    So time is 0.8625. 
    So It would be very helpful if anybody can describe me the best method to convert this float value into Hrs and Minutes.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, always remember to Google first! A query for `objective c integer to hours and minutes` will yield plenty of results.

Answer (score 0):

First we'd need to know the units of measurement. If you are calculating the distance in miles and the speed in miles per hour, then your final result is time expressed in hours.
If that is the case:

```
float timeInHours = distance / speed;

int hours = floorf(timeInHours);
int minutes =  roundf(60.0f * (timeInHours - hours));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is not giving accurate result.

Comment: What are the values you are using and the result you are getting? I just tried it with the following: 100 miles, at a 60 mph speed. The first line returns 1.6667. Second line returns 1. Third line 40. So it is one hour and forty minutes, which sounds correct to me.